# Using IMPORTRANGE within a FILTER

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, importrange

I found this question asked in other places, but I can't seem to get my formula correct...

```
=FILTER(ShortInventory!N:N , ROW(ShortInventory!N:N) =MAX( FILTER( 
ROW(ShortInventory!N:N) , NOT(ISBLANK(ShortInventory!N:N)))))
```

This works, pulling data from a secondary tab on the existing spreadsheet. I would like to pull this directly from the external spreadsheet.

```
=FILTER(IMPORTRANGE("SOURCE","Responses!N:N") , 
ROW(IMPORTRANGE("SOURCE","Responses!N:N")) =MAX( FILTER( 
ROW(IMPORTRANGE("SOURCE","Responses!N:N") , 
NOT(ISBLANK(IMPORTRANGE("SOURCE","Responses!N:N")))))))
```

I've tried variations of this and get the `#N/A`

> `FILTER` has mismatched range sizes. Expected row count: 122. column count: 1. Actual row count: 1, column count: 1.

I have no idea how to make this work.

Comment: I read about using QUERY with IMPORTRANGE in a FILTER, and modified my formula. It didn't work, but using this independently does reference the correct column. Searching for answers...

    =QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("Source","Responses!N:N"),"Select * where Col1 = '0'")

Comment: (Master with a tab pulling data from responses) https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1OKFFLT3SH2uZ-lYgD6pEr54ydBmbyHj6-GJeRojq0dE

(Responses) https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1gyAaxDzklUuhwBdLpMkb2jgrPmbJ9WxtdJ1JOO2d424

(Form) https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSdlqAoCeqYLU2utouBr_YarELbW0uCzuOUD9K4xfHHqHZeL7g/viewform

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
=FILTER(IMPORTRANGE("1gyAaxDzklUuhwBdLpMkb2jgrPmbJ9WxtdJ1JOO2d424","Responses!N1:N101"),
 ROW(A1:A101)=MAX(FILTER( ROW(A1:A101),NOT(
 ISBLANK(IMPORTRANGE("1gyAaxDzklUuhwBdLpMkb2jgrPmbJ9WxtdJ1JOO2d424","Responses!N1:N101"))))))
```

[image: 0]